# How to send the token from authClient to the store?

Tags: admin-on-rest

I have implemented admin-on-rest in another app and use the authClient.js as described in the walkthrough to save the token in localstoreage.

How would be the best approach to save the token also in my redux store? I cannot dispatch actions from the authClient function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [custom reducer](https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#customreducers) would probably work here. Catch the `USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS` action. Its payload will be whatever your `authClient` returns so make sure it contains your token.

Comment: Yes, the question is how to fire an action from the authClient (which is a function).

Comment: You can't, hence the custom reducer

Comment: The `USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS` is dispatched by AOR with the results of your authClient

Comment: Unfortunately the action type "AOR/USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS" has an empty payload (even though the auth client returns an object with the token on top level)

Comment: Nevermind, my custom authClient simply did not return anything - so I added the token to the return and we are golden. Thanks for your help!